# export All pages after API request

Tags: python-3.x, api

I have a problem after printing all information requested in my console. When I export the answer to my Excel sheet, I have only the last page. For my example page 9 only exported. how can I export all API request pages in excel? Thanks

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
from time import sleep
url='https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Series/Data?seriesCode=SI_POV_DAY1&areaCode=12&areaCode=24&areaCode=204&areaCode=72&areaCode=854&areaCode=108&areaCode=120&areaCode=132&areaCode=140&areaCode=148&areaCode=174&areaCode=178&areaCode=180&areaCode=384&areaCode=262&areaCode=818&areaCode=226&areaCode=232&areaCode=231&areaCode=266&areaCode=270&areaCode=288&areaCode=324&areaCode=624&areaCode=404&areaCode=426&areaCode=430&areaCode=434&areaCode=450&areaCode=454&areaCode=466&areaCode=478&areaCode=480&areaCode=504&areaCode=508&areaCode=516&areaCode=562&areaCode=566&areaCode=646&areaCode=678&areaCode=686&areaCode=690&areaCode=694&areaCode=706&areaCode=710&areaCode=728&areaCode=729&areaCode=748&areaCode=834&areaCode=768&areaCode=788&areaCode=800&areaCode=894&areaCode=716&timePeriod=%5B%221990%22%2C%222019%22%5D'
r=requests.get(url)
headers={
  "content-security-policy": "frame-src 'self' https://*.arcgis.com https://www.youtube.com https://youtube.com https://*.twitter.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://flickrembed.com/ https://public.tableau.com",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "date": "Tue, 30 Jun 2020 18:26:39 GMT",
  "feature-policy": "vibrate 'none'; geolocation 'none'; midi 'none'; notifications 'none'; push 'none'; sync-xhr 'none'; microphone 'none'; camera 'none'; magnetometer 'none'; gyroscope 'none'; speaker 'none'; vibrate 'none'; fullscreen 'none'; payment 'none'",
  "referrer-policy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  "server": "Kestrel",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
  "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "x-powered-by": "ASP.NET",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
}

json_data = r.json()

total_pages = int(json_data['totalPages'])
for page_no in range(1,9):
    url =f'https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Series/Data?page={page_no}&seriesCode=SI_POV_DAY1&areaCode=12&areaCode=24&areaCode=204&areaCode=72&areaCode=854&areaCode=108&areaCode=120&areaCode=132&areaCode=140&areaCode=148&areaCode=174&areaCode=178&areaCode=180&areaCode=384&areaCode=262&areaCode=818&areaCode=226&areaCode=232&areaCode=231&areaCode=266&areaCode=270&areaCode=288&areaCode=324&areaCode=624&areaCode=404&areaCode=426&areaCode=430&areaCode=434&areaCode=450&areaCode=454&areaCode=466&areaCode=478&areaCode=480&areaCode=504&areaCode=508&areaCode=516&areaCode=562&areaCode=566&areaCode=646&areaCode=678&areaCode=686&areaCode=690&areaCode=694&areaCode=706&areaCode=710&areaCode=728&areaCode=729&areaCode=748&areaCode=834&areaCode=768&areaCode=788&areaCode=800&areaCode=894&areaCode=716&timePeriod=%5B%221990%22%2C%222019%22%5D' 
    r = requests.get(url)
    json_data = r.json()
    my_dict = json_data['data']
    sleep(1.5)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='columns')
    print(my_dict)

df.to_excel (r'D:\local file\data3.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Great I found Solution

```
json_data = r.json()
df=[]
total_pages = int(json_data['totalPages'])
for page_no in range(1,9):
    url =f'https://unstats.un.org/SDGAPI/v1/sdg/Series/Data?page={page_no}&seriesCode=SI_POV_DAY1&areaCode=12&areaCode=24&areaCode=204&areaCode=72&areaCode=854&areaCode=108&areaCode=120&areaCode=132&areaCode=140&areaCode=148&areaCode=174&areaCode=178&areaCode=180&areaCode=384&areaCode=262&areaCode=818&areaCode=226&areaCode=232&areaCode=231&areaCode=266&areaCode=270&areaCode=288&areaCode=324&areaCode=624&areaCode=404&areaCode=426&areaCode=430&areaCode=434&areaCode=450&areaCode=454&areaCode=466&areaCode=478&areaCode=480&areaCode=504&areaCode=508&areaCode=516&areaCode=562&areaCode=566&areaCode=646&areaCode=678&areaCode=686&areaCode=690&areaCode=694&areaCode=706&areaCode=710&areaCode=728&areaCode=729&areaCode=748&areaCode=834&areaCode=768&areaCode=788&areaCode=800&areaCode=894&areaCode=716&timePeriod=%5B%221990%22%2C%222019%22%5D' 
    r = requests.get(url)
    json_data = r.json()
    df=df+json_data['data']

database = pd.DataFrame(df)
```